# Represent a set of non-uniform sized dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data source which can be represented as a list of maybe 30 dataframes (I'm saying dataframes, but if a better structure exists feel free to answer using that - nothing has been written yet). Each dataframe doesn't have any direct relationship to the other, but each has 3 columns and n rows. Column 1 is labels, column 2 and 3 are values (always numeric).

For tangibility, imagine each dataframe is a list of foods eaten at a party, and each column represents the number of each item Alice and Bob ate.

For example

```
A = [5 x 3] # (apples, pears, cookies, grapes, watermelon)
            # ---------------------------------------------------
            # item           Alice     Bob
            # apples           3        7
            # pears            1        2
            # cookies         10        4   
            # grapes         238      483
            # watermelon       0        1 
            # ---------------------------------------------------

B = [1 x 3] # (grapes)
C = [3 x 3] # (beef, rice, apples)
...
Z = [4 x 3] # (rice, grapes, watermelon, beef)
```

I want to represent these matrices as a data structure, such that I can ask

- General questions above all items - e.g. which of Alice and Bob ate most items overall, what was their average, standard deviation, etc
- Label specific questions - e.g. which of Alice and Bob at most grapes?

Whenever I have this kind of problem I always end up writing really ugly code which has lists of lists, requires the `[]` operator or `as.matrix()`/`as.list()`/`as.dataframe()` functions, and generally seems like a really crappy way of doing things.

What would be a goood/the best approach for these kind of data?

Comment: how about binding all of them together with `rbind` (and having their names as a separate column called say 'ID' (= A, B, ... Z)?

Comment: If multiple data frames have the sam item, how should they be combined? E.g. in your example both A and B contain a row for grapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on @Arun's comment, you can easily create a single data frame with another column indicating the party in question:

```
A = read.table(text="item           Alice     Bob
                     apples           3        7
                     pears            1        2
                     cookies         10        4   
                     grapes         238      483
                     watermelon       0        1", header=T)

B = read.table(text="item           Alice     Bob 
                     grapes          13       26", header=T)

C = read.table(text="item           Alice     Bob 
                     beef             1        3
                     rice             1        2
                     apples           1        0", header=T)

Z = read.table(text="item           Alice     Bob 
                     rice             2        1
                     grapes          10       15
                     watermelon       1        0
                     beef             0        2", header=T)

A$party = "A";    B$party = "B";    C$party = "C";    Z$party = "Z"
dframe = rbind(A, B, C, Z)
```

From there, you can get functions of the columns without difficulty:

```
apply(dframe[,2:3], 2, sum)
```

If you wanted to deal with individual items, and they had duplicates between the parties, you could perform [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) on the original data frames.  There's an SO thread on doing this in R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618).